# feed a command a comma separated list of file names in a directory, extract a variable motif from file names for labels

Tags: python, bash, terminal

I have a directory containing files that look like this:

```
1_reads.fastq
2_reads.fastq
89_reads.fastq
42_reads.fastq
```

I would like to feed a comma separated list of these file names to a command from a python program, so the input to the python command would like this:

```
program.py -i 1_reads.fastq,2_reads.fastq,89_reads.fastq,42_reads.fastq
```

Furthermore, I'd like to use the numbers in the file names for a labeling function within the python command such that the input would look like this:

```
program.py -i 1_reads.fastq,2_reads.fastq,89_reads.fastq,42_reads.fastq -t s1,s2,s89,s42
```

Its important that the file names and the label IDs are in the same order.

Comment: What happens if you have a name with a comma in it? "Comma-separated" isn't used by standard tools for good reason. (Even those tools that accept lists of names in newline-separated format increasingly allow NUL-delimited streams as a more robust alternative).

Comment: If I understood your question I think you could rephrase it to: "How to convert a list of filenames in a comma separated list?

Answer (score 3):

First: This is a very poorly-thought-out calling convention. Don't use it.

However, if you're using software someone else wrote that already has that convention baked in...

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=, # use comma as separator

files=( [[:digit:]]*_* )
[[ -e $files || -L $files ]] || { echo "ERROR: No files matching glob exist" >&2; exit 1; }

prefixes=( )
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  prefixes+=( "s${file%%_*}" )
done

# "exec" only if this is the last command in the script; remove otherwise
exec program.py -i "${files[*]}" -t "${prefixes[*]}"
```

How this works:

- `IFS=,` causes `${array[*]}` to put a comma between each expanded element. Thus, expanding `${files[*]}` and `${prefixes[*]}` creates comma-separated strings with the contents of each array.
- `${file%%_*}` removes everything after the first `_` in a filename, allowing the numbers alone to be extracted.
- `[[ -e $files || -L $files ]]` actually only tests whether the first element in that array exists (as a symlink or otherwise); however, this will always be true if the glob being expanded to form the array matched any files (unless files have been deleted between the two lines' invocation).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
program.py $(cd DIR && var=$(ls) && echo $var | tr ' ' ',')
```

That will pass to program.py the string returned by te command line inside the $(..).

That command line will: Enter in your directory, run ls storing the output in a variable, that will remove the newline characters replacing with spaces, and it doesn't add a trailing space. Then echo that variable to 'tr' which will translate spaces to commas.

Comment: `(cd "$dir" && names=( * ) && { IFS=','; echo "${names[*]}"; })`, if you **really** want to do this. There's no excuse for `ls`.

Comment: Also, `echo $var | ...` will change tabs in names to spaces, expand globs in names into lists of other files, etc; you need to quote your expansions to stop them from messing things up. Even then, `echo $var` will behave in undefined ways if you have a file named `-n`.

Comment: Also, put a `&&` after your `cd DIR`; otherwise, this code will generate a list of files in the current directory if that `cd` fails.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess in his case that won't be a concern since the filenames on his directory seem to adhere to a safe filename pattern.

Comment: I once saw multiple TB of access-log backups used for billing deleted because someone had a script that assumed all files would adhere to a safe pattern -- and then a buffer overflow in one of the tools creating files in that directory dumped random garbage into a filename, which happened to include a `*` with whitespace on both sides. Point of that lesson: Take caution even when you don't think it matters, and you'll avoid finding yourself in a world of hurt when it turns out that it does.

Comment: also, `echo $var` will still misbehave even with these regular filenames if, for instance, `IFS=_`. Change it to `echo "$var"` and you avoid the risk. Change it to `printf '%s\n' "$var"` and you also avoid the `-n` case, and cases (like backslashes) which don't misbehave with bash in particular, but which the POSIX spec for `echo` *allows* to behave in manners other than what you intend with other shells.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done easily in pure Bash. Make sure you run from within the directory that contains the files.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

# Create an array of files
f=( +([[:digit:]])_reads.fastq )

# Check that there are some files...
if ((${#f[@]}==0)); then
    echo "No files found. Exiting."
    exit
fi

# Create an array of labels, directly from the array f:

# Remove trailing _reads.fastq
l=( "${f[@]%_reads.fastq}" )
# And prepend the letter s
l=( "${l[@]/#/s}" )

# Now the arrays f and l are good: check them:
declare -p f l

# To join the arrays, we'll use eval. Safe because the code is single-quoted!
IFS=, eval 'program.py -i "${f[*]}" -t "${l[*]}"'
```

---

**Note.** The use of `eval` here is perfectly safe as we're passing a constant string (and it's actually an idiomatic way to join an array without using a subshell or a loop). Don't modify the command, in particular the single quotes.

<sub>Thanks to Charles Duffy who convinced me to add healthy comments about the use of `eval`</sub>